# Can someone please explain what the block of code below is used for in SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, pnp, pnpjs

Can someone please explain what the block of code below is used for in SPFx?

```
sp.setup({spfxContext: this.props.context});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the required step while using SP PnP JS module in SPFx solution.

Using this code, you set the SPFx context within the SP PnP JS library.

> Because SharePoint Framework provides a local context to each component we need to set that context within the library. This allows us to determine request urls as well as use the SPFx HttpGraphClient within @pnp/graph.
>
> The setup is always done in the onInit method to ensure it runs before your other life-cycle code.

**Using @pnp/sp setup**

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

// ...
protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
  return super.onInit().then(_ => {
    // other init code may be present
    sp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.context
    });
  });
}

// ...
```

**Source**: [PnP JS - Getting Started](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/)